# Как задать border у определенной колонки таблицы и убрать ее по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно задать стили и onClick, чтобы при выборе соответствующего переключателя radio вокруг 2-й (4-й) колонки появлялась рамка:

```js
function Select(that) {}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="id1"></colgroup>

  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="id2"></colgroup>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type=radio name=r onClick="Select(this);"> </td>
    <td><label>Блок1</label></td>
    <td> <input type=radio name=r onClick="Select(this);"> </td>
    <td><label>Блок2</label></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст1</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст2</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст4</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст5</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Select(that) {
  tdEach = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (var i = 0; i < tdEach.length; i++) {
    tdEach[i].style.borderColor = "transparent";
  }

  cellNum = that.parentElement.cellIndex;

  trEach = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < trEach.length; i++) {
    trChoosen = trEach[i].children[cellNum];
    trChoosen.style.borderLeft = "1px solid";
    trChoosen.style.borderRight = "1px solid";

  };
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

td:nth-child(2n) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="id1"></colgroup>

  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup id="id2"></colgroup>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type=radio name=r onClick="Select(this);"> </td>
    <td><label>Блок1</label></td>
    <td> <input type=radio name=r onClick="Select(this);"> </td>
    <td><label>Блок2</label></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст1</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст2</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст4</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>текст5</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Не работает так, как нужно. Рамка не появляется.

Comment: Извините, в новых браузерах работает.